# PHP Sorting Algorithm to Arrange Texts no Alphabetical

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I want to arrange texts from SQL using PHP loops and array. But I cannot figure out how to do it. I'd like to check other algorithms if there is.
The texts already got their set order value:
Banana - 1st; Apple - 2nd; Orange - 3rd.

**INPUT:**

```
- Apple  
- Orange  
- Banana
```

**OUTPUT:**

> - Banana
> - Apple
> - Orange

I already tried array sorting but didn't work as expected.

-By the way, I solved this problem by using another database table.

Comment: Provide your `SQL` query

Comment: What have you tried till now, at least mention that.

Comment: I already tried array sorting but didn't work as expected.
it will just sort it alphabetically.
I solved the issue but using other method like using another SQL table that has the texts already sorted.

Comment: You don't need to sort, you already have the required order in that extra array. Just *foreach* over it, and map the value to whatever you want to display.

Answer (score 0):

You can sort array this way:

```
$array = ['Apple', 'Orange', 'Banana'];
sort($array);
```

**output:**

```
Apple
Banana
Orange
```

Comment: Yeah this is a sort, but I believe OP wants: [Banana, Apple, Orange] as a result :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in a query:

```
ORDER BY FIELD(`fruit`.`name`, 'Banana','Apple','Orange')
```

All `Banana` will be returned first, then `Apple`, then `Orange`, then everything else.